# Sympy solver bug in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

So I'm playing with Sympy in an effort to build a generic solver/generator of physics problems. One component is that I'm going for a function that will take kwargs and, according to what it got, rearrange the equation and substitute values in it. Thanks to SO, I managed to find the things I need for that.

However..... I've tried putting `sympy.solve` in a for loop to generate all those expressions and I've ran into.... something.

```
import sympy
R, U, I, eq = sympy.symbols('R U I eq')
eq = R - U/I
for x in 'RUI':
    print(x)
    print(sympy.solve(eq, x))
```

The output?

```
R
[U/I]
U
[I*R]
I
[]
```

However, whenever I do `sympy.solve(eq, I)` it works and returns `[U/R]`.

Now, I'm guessing the issue is with sympy using `I` for imaginary unit and with variable hiding in blocks, but even when I transfer the symbol declaration inside the for loop (and equation as well), I still get the same problem.

I'm not sure I'll need this badly in the end, but this is interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more like an undocumented feature than a bug. The loop `for x in 'RUI'`    is equivalent to `for x in ['R', 'U', 'I']`, meaning that x runs over one-character **strings**, not sympy symbols. Insert `print(type(x))` in the loop to see this. And note that  `sympy.solve(eq, 'I')` returns `[]`.

The loop `for x in [R, U, I]` solves correctly for each variable. This is the right way to write this loop.

The surprising thing is that you get anything at all when passing a string as the second argument of `solve`. [Sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) does not list strings among acceptable arguments. Apparently, it tries to coerce the string to a sympy object and does not always guess your meaning correctly: works with `sympy.solve(eq, 'R')` but not with `sympy.solve(eq, 'I')`

Comment: So, basically, the "bug" isn't in `I`, but in `R` and `U`? That makes sense, in the sense that sympy bugfeaturedly takes string as symbol, unless the string is `I`, which it uses for imaginary unit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that some sympy functions "accidentally" work with strings as input because they call `sympify` on their input. But `sympify('I')` gives the imaginary unit (sqrt(-1)), not Symbol('I').

You should always define your symbols explicitly like

```
R, U, I = symbols("R U I")
```

and use those instead of strings.

See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Idioms-and-Antipatterns#strings-as-input for more information on why you should avoid using strings with SymPy.